# Page isn't working when insert data to mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi

Good day. I have a simple html file with 2 button, when button clicked, it will input some data to database. Unfortunately, when the button is clicked, chrome displays `192.168.0.168 is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500`

The following is my html code snippet

```
<form action="mode.php" method="POST">
<input style="background-color: green;" id="home" name="home" type="submit" value="HOME"></br>
<input style="background-color: red;" id="away" name="away" type="submit" value="AWAY">
</form>
```

and this is the `mode.php` coding:

```
<?php

   $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
   $dbuser = 'xxx';
   $dbpass = 'abc1234';
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
if (isset($_POST['home'])) {
$sql= insert into home_mode (id, status) value (null, "HOME");

mysql_select_db('home_mode');

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

echo "Mode changed to HOME";}
?>
```

---

*I have tested the connection to MySQL with a test script and it's successful.
Please assist, thank you!

Comment: Why you inserting `NULL` on `id`?

Comment: @S.I. Hi, it's an auto increment field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to insert `NULL` on auto increment column. Remove `NULL` from `INSERT` query and try like this:

```
$sql= insert into home_mode (status) value ("HOME");
```

Also you really should consider and change old, deprecated `mysql_*` to [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Update: Selecting last inserted row

```
$select_last_row = SELECT MAX( status ) FROM  home_mode
```

Comment: Yea, it's working now after I use `mysqli` Do you have any idea how to retrieve last input of the status column? I use the command `$last_status = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM home_mode ORDER BY status DESC LIMIT 1");` and `echo "The current HOME MODE is $last_status";`, but the `last_status` variable wont show up. Thanks